# Camera service binder died after zooming

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera, zooming, android-binder

I'm capturing a large Bitmap after zooming on TextureView and I get this error after several shot only on some devices and nothing found about this on the web :

```
2019-12-29 19:27:37.940 3687-26031/? E/CameraService: binderDied: Java client's binder died, removing it from the list of active clients
2019-12-29 19:27:37.978 17082-17082/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2019-12-29 19:27:37.981 17082-17082/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2019-12-29 19:27:38.000 17087-17087/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2019-12-29 19:27:38.000 4135-4170/? E/WindowManager: RemoteException occurs on reporting focusChanged, w=Window{fa8df75 u0 klyss.com.mainapp/klyss.com.mainapp.Home.MainActivity}
    android.os.DeadObjectException
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:1143)
        at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.windowFocusChanged(IWindow.java:500)
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowState.reportFocusChangedSerialized(WindowState.java:3943)
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(WindowManagerService.java:5470)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
        at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:44)
2019-12-29 19:27:38.000 17087-17087/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2019-12-29 19:27:38.013 17092-17092/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2019-12-29 19:27:38.014 17092-17092/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2019-12-29 19:27:38.023 17092-17092/? E/.gms.persisten: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-12-29 19:27:38.023 17082-17082/? E/android:drmSer: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-12-29 19:27:38.026 17087-17087/? E/id.app.launche: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-12-29 19:27:38.266 4135-4150/? E/PackageManager: Optimistic bind failed.
    java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: [Optimistic Bind] Didn't bind to resolver in time!
        at com.android.server.pm.InstantAppResolverConnection.waitForBindLocked(InstantAppResolverConnection.java:160)
        at com.android.server.pm.InstantAppResolverConnection.bind(InstantAppResolverConnection.java:225)
        at com.android.server.pm.InstantAppResolverConnection.lambda$optimisticBind$0(InstantAppResolverConnection.java:255)
        at com.android.server.pm.-$$Lambda$InstantAppResolverConnection$D-JKXi4qrYjnPQMOwj8UtfZenps.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

Where does it usually come from ?